# How to handle "Session state exceeds the 110kb size limit." in BotBuilder framework?

Tags: botframework

When I chat with my bot, sometimes I get some images back. When I receive 4 images throughout a conversation, the 5th attempt to return dialog with an image will get this error:  `Error: Session state exceeds the 110kb size limit.` and my bot will stop functioning.

Is there a way to resolve this? I've tried clearing the session data after each utterance but that doesn't help.

I'm using CosmosDB for storage.

Here is the more of the error code info:

```
  statusText: 'Bad Request',
  status: 400,
  code: 400,
  body: '{"error":"Session state exceeds the 110kb size limit","code":400}',
```

Comment: what channel are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Web Chat channel